# Packer Errors on Attempt to Run A Script

Tags: docker, packer

I have a Packer build that is using GitHub actions.
The build needs to run a bash script that dockerizes the applications.
I know it's not best practice, but I have to ensure that the script can be used during the Packer build.

I get the following error:

```sh
Error: /15 04:59:23 packer-plugin-amazon_v1.0.6_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2022/01/15 04:59:23 [ERROR] Remote command exited with '1': chmod +x /tmp/script_1771.sh; ARTIFACT_TOKEN='<sensitive>' ARTIFACT_USER='octane-writer' BUILD_BRANCH='caching' BUILD_NUMBER='99' CI_ID='<some_url>' PACKER_BUILDER_TYPE='amazon-ebs' PACKER_BUILD_NAME='ubuntu' USE_PICSS='0' VAULT_APPROLE_IDS='<sensitive>'  /tmp/script_1771.sh
```

The remote script looks like this as per the inline provisioner based off what's in the repository (WHICH I CANNOT SHARE BECAUSE IT'S AN INTERNAL REPO)!!! I have tried multiple ways in attempting to change the provisioner `shell` block, but have gotten nowhere.

The following was an attempt to see about passing it off to use the root user, but that fails as well:

Passing off commands to use the root user:

```sh
  provisioner "shell" {
    environment_vars = [
      "USE_PICSS=${var.USE_PICSS}",
      "ARTIFACT_USER=${var.ARTIFACT_USER}",
      "ARTIFACT_TOKEN=${var.ARTIFACT_TOKEN}",
      "VAULT_APPROLE_IDS=${var.VAULT_APPROLE_IDS}",
      "BUILD_NUMBER=${var.BUILD_NUMBER}",
      "BUILD_BRANCH=${var.BUILD_BRANCH}",
      "CI_ID=${var.CI_CD}"
    ]
    inline = [
      "echo '======================================'",
      "echo '         checking system+config       '",
      "echo '======================================'",
      "whoami",
      "sudo su -c 'cat /etc/shadow' -s /bin/sh root",
      "sudo su -c 'export USE_PICSS=${var.USE_PICSS}' -s /bin/sh root",
      "sudo su -c 'export ARTIFACT_USER=${var.ARTIFACT_USER}' -s /bin/sh root",
      "sudo su -c 'export ARTIFACT_TOKEN=${var.ARTIFACT_TOKEN}' -s /bin/sh root",
      "sudo su -c 'echo $ARTIFACT_USER",
      "sudo su -c 'echo $ARTIFACT_TOKEN",
      "echo '======================================'",
      "echo '           checking env               '",
      "echo '======================================'",
      "sudo su -c 'printenv' -s /bin/sh root",
      "echo '======================================'",
      "echo '           packer app                 '",
      "echo '======================================'",
      "cd /tmp/build-system/",
      "sed '2 i set -e' dockerized.sh",
      "sudo su -c  './dockerized.sh make r510_octane_defconfig' -s /bin/sh root",
      "sudo su -c  './dockerized.sh make -C output/r510_octane/ all' -s /bin/sh root"
    ]
  }
```

Here is the main one and what we are trying to get working:

```sh
  provisioner "shell" {
    environment_vars = [
      "USE_PICSS=${var.USE_PICSS}",
      "ARTIFACT_USER=${var.ARTIFACT_USER}",
      "ARTIFACT_TOKEN=${var.ARTIFACT_TOKEN}",
      "VAULT_APPROLE_IDS=${var.VAULT_APPROLE_IDS}",
      "BUILD_NUMBER=${var.BUILD_NUMBER}",
      "BUILD_BRANCH=${var.BUILD_BRANCH}",
      "CI_ID=${var.CI_CD}"
    ]
    inline = [
      "whoami",
      "export USE_PICSS=${var.USE_PICSS}",
      "export ARTIFACT_USER=${var.ARTIFACT_USER}",
      "export ARTIFACT_TOKEN=${var.ARTIFACT_TOKEN}",
      "printenv",
      "cd /tmp/build-system/",
      "sed '2 i set -x' dockerized.sh",
      "./dockerized.sh make r510_octane_defconfig",
      "./dockerized.sh make -C output/r510_octane/ all"
    ]
  }
```

I would appreciate any insights, I did find this: https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell#sudo-example

Unfortunately, I am pretty new to Packer and am trying to see how I can resolve this issue. Any advice and or help would be greatly appreciated here.

Comment: You can try executing the shell script on the instance manually to see the specific error. It does seem to be executing a `dockerized.sh`, and I do not see that payload delivered in a provisioner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out, the payloads were delivered, but the Packer user was using a different shell and the script was exiting with a specific code and it was not working. So I defined the `valid_exit_codes` and invoked them with `bash` in front of the script and it worked:

```sh
  provisioner "shell" {
    valid_exit_codes = [
      "0",
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
    environment_vars = [
      "USE_PICSS=${var.USE_PICSS}",
      "ARTIFACT_USER=${var.ARTIFACT_USER}",
      "ARTIFACT_TOKEN=${var.ARTIFACT_TOKEN}",
      "VAULT_APPROLE_IDS=${var.VAULT_APPROLE_IDS}",
      "BUILD_NUMBER=${var.BUILD_NUMBER}",
      "BUILD_BRANCH=${var.BUILD_BRANCH}",
      "CI_ID=${var.CI_CD}"
    ]
    inline = [
      "whoami",
      "echo $SHELL",
      "export USE_PICSS=${var.USE_PICSS}",
      "export ARTIFACT_USER=${var.ARTIFACT_USER}",
      "export ARTIFACT_TOKEN=${var.ARTIFACT_TOKEN}",
      "printenv",
      "cd /tmp/build-system/",
      "pwd",
      "ls -laH",
      "sed '2 i set -x' dockerized.sh",
      "bash ./dockerized.sh make r510_octane_defconfig",
      "bash ./dockerized.sh make -C output/r510_octane/ all"
    ]
  }
```