# Packer build .json file for Linux image creation-Builds finished but no artifacts were created

Tags: azure, powershell, packer

I executed the below packer.json file in windows powershell to create a Linux image

```
{
    "builders": [{
        "type": "azure-arm",
        
        "client_id": "fb61f35d-99c5-43f8-9444-f4a3b96fd1f0",
        "client_secret": "DV-8Q~CJCeAfsc.WBm5eJ5ItVdcqnUebd3zhJb-o",
        "tenant_id": "67b304ff-0032-477b-b33f-c7a9de6ab0a5",
        "subscription_id": "315c9c99-62bc-42ff-bd23-d85a808a5609",
        
    "managed_image_name": "MyUbuntuImage",
    "managed_image_resource_group_name": "newgroup",
    
    "os_type": "Linux",
    "image_publisher": "Canonical",
    "image_offer": "UbuntuServer",
    "image_sku": "16.04-LTS",
    
    "location": "eastus",
    "vm_size": "standard_B1ms"
}],
"provisioners":[{
    "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .path }}'",
    "inline": [
    "apt-get update",
    "apt-get install nginx -y",
    "apt-get install stress -y",
    "systemct1 enable nginx",
    "/usr/sbin/waagent -force -deprovision+user && export HISTSIZE=0 && sync"
    ],
    "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
    "type": "shell"
    }]
    }
```

Everything was created, deleted properly. however, the image is not created. Below are the last few lines from powershell-

Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> azure-arm: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 1. Allowed exit codes are: [0]

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.

Im using packer_1.8.3_windows_amd64 version

Answer (score 0):

The error message commonly represents that it **not able to access** the server or we are passing **wrong value**.

#### Ways to fix the issue

If you set **"use_env_var_file": true** you have to use the **execute_command** is

```bash
 "execute_command": "chmod +x {{.Path}}; . {{.EnvVarFile}} && {{.Path}} sudo -E sh '{{ .path }}'"
```

If you are set **"use_env_var_file": false** you can use the same as you used.

```json
 "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .path }}'",
```

The issue may happen because of Packer user using different shell. To avoid this, you can use **valid_exit_codes** in a provisioner. As [R. Barrett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70719041/packer-errors-on-attempt-to-run-a-script) has mentioned in his answer

```json
"provisioners":[{
    valid_exit_codes = [
          "0",
          "1",
          "2"
        ]
     "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .path }}'",
    "inline": [
        .....
```